# Can a kotlin annotation inject code into a method?

Tags: android, kotlin

The documentation says: "Annotations are means of attaching metadata to code".
But only that? Can it run code before a method is invoked?

I want to implement an API check before a method is invoked such that if it doesn't match the required API level then an exception is thrown. Is it possible?

Comment: No. You can write an annotation processor that will throw an error during compilation, but that would be quite complicated. It would be far easier to make a `checkAPILevel` function that can throw an error and put that as the first line of your functions that need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how complicated? Could you send me some example if you know one?

Comment: Just google "java annotation processor" and the first few hits will give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah it really looks too overkill. It’s a pity.